# How can I get a datetime from this string '01/25/1955'?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
Dim dtDoM As Nullable(Of DateTime)
If (txtMarriageDate.Text.Trim = "") Then
            dtDoM = Nothing
        Else

            dtDoM = DateTime.ParseExact(txtMarriageDate.Text.Trim + " 00:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            'dtDoM = Convert.ToDateTime(txtMarriageDate.Text)
        End If
```

On the commented out section I was getting FormatException 'String not recognized as datetime' and on the new code I'm getting "System.FormatException = {"The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."}"

EDIT: Answered. Can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date (01/25/1955) is in `MM/dd/yyyy` format, you're using `dd/MM/yyyy` in your format string.

Try using this: `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: Oh my. I hate working with other peoples code. Can't believe I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong format string. You want `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`, judging by your examples.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I overlooked that. Any idea why this doesn't work? 'dtDoM = Convert.ToDateTime(txtMarriageDate.Text)"

Comment: If the input is correct, it should have worked. Typically you need to validate that the input string is formatted exactly the way you think it is, which is why I prefer the `ParseExact` approach.

Answer (score 1):

You got day and month reversed. This will work:

```
dtDoM = DateTime.ParseExact(txtMarriageDate.Text.Trim + " 00:00:00", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```